# Change CSS with JSOUP Java

Tags: java, css, jsoup

I have this String, that consists of HTML syntax, but there are some CSS tags also, for example :

```
<style type='text/css'> #gallery-1 { margin: auto; } #gallery-1 .gallery-item { float: left; margin-top: 10px; text-align: center; width: 25%; } #gallery-1 img { border: 2px solid #cfcfcf; } #gallery-1 .gallery-caption { margin-left: 0; } /* see gallery_shortcode() in wp-includes/media.php */ </style>
```

And I would like to change `width: 25%;` to `width : 100%;` with the help of JSOUP. How can I access the CSS tags in String like this ?

Comment: Try this http://cssparser.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Jsoup does not parse CSS, but if you only care about this particular page, you can change the element's text: `element.text(element.text().replace("width : 25%;", "width : 100%;"));`

For more general CSS transformation, you'll want an actual CSS parser, such as [the one](http://cssparser.sourceforge.net/) suggested in Shahrukh's comment.